# cron does not working for my python program

Tags: python, cron

I face to problem of my CRON job does not working at all.
Currently I am trying to run my Python program with CRON on Ubuntu 16.04(Friendly core xential).

I typed crontab -e in terminal and added line as below however it does not work.

```
*/5 * * * * /root/test.py
```

I would like to run this "test.py" program every 5 minutes. I can run this program manually without any problems.

Does anyone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: I just guess that this is because test.py does not have executable ? do I need to chmod a+x?

Comment: `chmod a+x` is a start. I'm assuming you're running this script as root, correct? Does it have a python interpreter defined at the beginning, e.g. `#!/usr/bin/python3`?

Comment: hi ajgringo619 thanks for your reply. As you assumed I ma running script as root. "#!/usr/bin/python3" is defined at the beginning but because of # ? the row become red in color is that OK? ie. I know its out of date but I am using python2.7 on this machine though.

Comment: its still not working after i put #!/usr/bin/python2.7 with cron

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're trying to run this program as root, you have (2) options to fix this:

1. Move the crontab entry to root's crontab:
   this is the easiest option, does not require any external programs or configurations. To edit root's crontab, type `sudo crontab -e` from the terminal, then add this entry:

   `*/5 * * * * /root/test.py`
2. Change the current crontab entry to this:

   `*/5 * * * * sudo /root/test.py`.

   You will then need to add the following entry with `sudo visudo` so that this command will run without prompting for a password:

   `your_username        ALL=(ALL:ALL)   NOPASSWD: /root/test.py`

I would go with option #1; it's easier to change in the future.

Comment: Hello ajgringo619, as you mentioned solution 1, I edited crontab with command sudo crontab -e however still not running. what I can do for this?

Comment: What exactly did you put in your root's crontab? Did you add `sudo`, by chance?

Comment: hi firstly I add */5 * * * * sudo /root/test.py  but it still doesn't work so I move my python program to the directly which running command in that python program located. /usr/local/src/m24o8l-usbrh-5afcea2/ .    and change crontab - e */5 * * * * sudo /usr/local/src/m24o8l-usbrh-5afcea2/test.py . but still not working. so I typed "which python2.7" and get PATH "/usr/bin/python2.7" so I wrote crontab -e as"*/5 * * * * sudo /usr/bin/python2.7 /usr/local/src/m24o8l-usbrh-5afcea2/test.py" but still nor working....

Comment: If you're using root's crontab, you do not need sudo (this is option #1).

Comment: so do you mean i should try option2?

Comment: OK, I clarified my answer. Does it make more sense now?

Comment: finally I found that this is not cron problem but python program has error.